# How to show logo screen animated with launching apple?

Tags: iphone, graphical-logo

I am going to show the logo screen with launching the apple appearing from centure animated.
Some apples appear as this.
Now my logo screen appears immediately when the apple finished launching after black screen.
I think that it can be proceed without my code.
Help me who knows how to...
Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create logo screen in iphone size . and name it as Default.png to launch when app start. it will show the image in place of black screen.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. The apple properly work. But I don't know where I can customize that the image name.